# What to use for a job scheduler for a .net app with plugins for each job

Tags: .net, azure, quartz.net, job-scheduling, hangfire

I'm creating a .net app in which many clients will have their own scheduled tasks. Each client will be a plugin that gets added to the main app with their own jobs and settings for when to run. What I'm looking to do is have create a job scheduler that will find all the tasks and run them based on the client settings.I'm looking at hangfire, quartz.net, and azure functions/webjobs.

Since this will be hosted on azure, I'm leaning towards an azure function that would run every minute, read a database to find each task, use reflection to find the scheduled task class since they're plugins, check the settings for how often to run the task and run it accordingly. I would just like to hear some ideas from what others have tried with success